# Plot all columns from a dataframe

Tags: r, plot

I want to plot all the columns Wine_1 to Wine_30 in a single smoothed line plot from [the file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1teXUtzEbsTrn-4ncwf8zYn4gBvPY6uv0/view?usp=sharing) sheet 7, I am trying with the following:

```
#Imports Dataset
library(readxl)#
RMN <- read_excel("~/R/ProyectoAspectosAnaliticos/DatosDeVinos.xlsx", sheet=7)
RMN <- as.data.frame(RMN)
attach(RMN)
plot(PPM,Wine_1,type="l",col="red")
lines(PPM,Wine_2,col="green")
#And I can take from here to the 30 but that will not be optimal to do
```

Is there any other optimal way where I can graph all the 30 curves in the y axis, and with the x axis fixed in the PPM columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can turn the data frame to long form and then use `facet_wrap()` to split the plots by variable:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggplot2)
RMN    = read.xlsx("DatosDeVinos.xlsx", sheet = "RMN")
df     = subset(RMN, selec = -c(Value))
dfLong = gather(df, key = "Variable", value="Value", -PPM)
ggplot(dfLong, aes(x=PPM, y = Value)) + facet_wrap(~Variable) + theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.spacing = unit(0, "lines"))
```

Comment: Would you mind marking this as solved if it solved your problem?